# Persistence unit not found but the file is there

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans

I use netbeans and I have problem to compile.

I get No persistence unit with name 'NotionService' found

In this folder
/home/bob/dev/storm/src/main/webapp/META-INF/

i have context.xml and persistence.xml

any idea?

Comment: have you really named 'NotionService' your persistence unit in persistence.xml file. You really should check. Otherwise to get more answers you should add more information to your question.

Comment: and what is in the CLASSPATH ? because where your source files are doesn't mean much ... it is dependent on your build

Answer (score 0):

Your persistence.xml ultimately should be in

**webapp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF**

NOT

**webapp/META-INF**

Your **webapp/META-INF** location should still have the context.xml file.

Comment: This is false, I have project with the file in META-INF directly that work perfectly.